# Get details from recyclerview and show result in another fragment using cardview with retrofit 2 networking library

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

Iam using cardview in recyclerview to list the result of retrofit request, next I want to get details of cardview that was clicked and display the details of cardview (json) in a fragment (To be concise I'm using fragments for listing and showing details)

The below code is my first fragment in which I'm fetching the json using retrofit 2. This code is working fine, giving the out put json.

```
  public class AgentAssetsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    public TextView titleName, assetRate, assetBrand;
    public RecyclerView assetRecyclerView;
    List<AgentAsset> data;
    AgentAssetsAdapter agentAssetsAdapter;
    FrameLayout mLoadingFrame;
    public SharedPreferences pref;

    public AgentAssetsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agent_assets, container, false);
        assetRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentAssetListRecyclerId);
        titleName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.assetTitleId);
        assetRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.assetRateId);
        assetBrand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.assetBrandId);
        mLoadingFrame = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.agentLoadingFrame);
        initViews();
        mLoadingFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return view;
    }

    private void initViews() {
        assetRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager assetGridManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        assetRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(assetGridManager);
        assetRecyclerView.setAdapter(agentAssetsAdapter);
        getAssets();
    }

    private void getAssets() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LoginActivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String acToken = pref.getString("token", "DEFAULT");
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + acToken)
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        final ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        final AssetRequest assetRequest = new AssetRequest();

        final Call<List<AgentAsset>> call = apiInterface.getAssetListOfAgent();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<AgentAsset>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<AgentAsset>> call, Response<List<AgentAsset>> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();

                if (statusCode == 200 && response.body() != null) {

                    List<AgentAsset> agentAssets = response.body();
                    data = agentAssets;

                    agentAssetsAdapter = new AgentAssetsAdapter(data);
                    id = agentAssetsAdapter.agentAssetId;
                    assetRecyclerView.setAdapter(agentAssetsAdapter);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), data.size() + " results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (statusCode == 406) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your token expired " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (response.body() == null) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No results " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Network error, try again later " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                mLoadingFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<AgentAsset>> call, Throwable t) {
                mLoadingFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error, Check your network ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("AgentAsset GET Failure", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

This is my adapter class for inflating the RecyclerView, in which I am using cardview to indicate each item. I am able to get the position of item clicked, but when i try to get the id of the item its always showing the id of last item in the list. I dont know why, tried every question in stackoverflow from this morning, didn't find a result for my query.

```
    public class AgentAssetsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AgentAssetsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<AgentAsset> agentAssetLists;
    private static AgentAssetClickListener agentAssetClickListener;
    Integer agentAssetId;
    String href;

    public AgentAssetsAdapter(List<AgentAsset> agentAssetLists) {
        this.agentAssetLists = agentAssetLists;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return agentAssetLists.size();
    }

    public interface AgentAssetClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    @Override
    public AgentAssetsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.agent_asset_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AgentAssetsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (agentAssetLists != null) {

            holder.titleName.setText(agentAssetLists.get(position).getName());
            holder.assetBrand.setText(agentAssetLists.get(position).getBrand().getName());
            agentAssetId = agentAssetLists.get(position).getIdBrand();
            href = agentAssetLists.get(position).getLinks().getSelf().getHref();

            if (agentAssetLists.get(position).getRank() == -1) {
                holder.agentRank.setText("");
            } else {
                holder.agentRank.setText(String.valueOf(agentAssetLists.get(position).getRank()));
            }

            if (Objects.equals(agentAssetLists.get(position).getRate().getAvailable().toString(), "0")) {
                holder.assetRate.setText("nil");
            } else {
                holder.assetRate.setText(String.valueOf(agentAssetLists.get(position).getRate().getValue()));
            }

            if (Objects.equals(agentAssetLists.get(position).getBestRate().getAvailable().toString(), "0")) {
                holder.agentRate.setText("nil");
            } else {
                holder.agentRate.setText(String.valueOf(agentAssetLists.get(position).getBestRate().getValue()));
            }

        } else {

            holder.resultCount.setText("No Assets, Try Later");
        }

    }

    public void addItems(List<AgentAsset> asResponse, int index) {
        int cursize = agentAssetLists.size();
        agentAssetLists.addAll(index, asResponse);
        if (getItemCount() != 0) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(index, (agentAssetLists.size() - cursize));
        } else {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView titleName, assetRate, assetBrand, agentRate, agentRank, resultCount;
        ImageView assetImage;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            resultCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultCountId);
            titleName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentAssetTitleId);
            assetRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.assetRateId);
            assetBrand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentAssetBrandId);
            agentRank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentRankId);
            agentRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentAssetRateId);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            //img_android = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Log.d("item clicked", "item clicked" + getAdapterPosition() );
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "clicked aaa " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(AgentAssetClickListener agentAssetClickListener) {
        AgentAssetsAdapter.agentAssetClickListener = agentAssetClickListener;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```

How to get the id from the item clicked ? and how to pass the data to next fragment which shows complete details of the current clicked cardview ? Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I forgot to attach my json response, here is it

```
 [
  {
    "id_asset": 1,
    "id_category": 1,
    "id_brand": 2,
    "name": "Samsung Galaxy 6",
    "status": 1,
    "updated_at": "Oct 3, 2016 10:24:28 AM",
    "rank": 1,
    "rate": {
      "available": 1,
      "id_asset_rate": 2,
      "id_asset": 1,
      "id_user": 10,
      "value": 5000,
      "loan_to_value": 50,
      "offered": 2500,
      "annual_rate": 3,
      "quantity": 5,
      "status": 1,
      "created_at": 1477200691,
      "updated_at": 1477200751
    },
    "best_rate": {
      "available": 1,
      "id_asset": 1,
      "value": 5000,
      "loan_to_value": 50,
      "offered": 2500,
      "annual_rate": 3,
      "quantity": 5,
      "rank": 1
    },
    "category": {
      "id_category": 1,
      "id_parent": 0,
      "name": "Mobile Phones",
      "image": "",
      "sort": 1,
      "status": 1,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/v1/categories/1"
        }
      }
    },
    "brand": {
      "id_brand": 2,
      "name": "Samsung",
      "status": 1,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "/v1/assets/1"
      }
    }
  } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite your id on every onBind in your adapter:

Here you should get null, because the id is never set before the adapter is set to an RecyclerView:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<AgentAsset>> call, Response<List<AgentAsset>> response) {
    //...
    if (statusCode == 200 && response.body() != null) {
        //...
        agentAssetsAdapter = new AgentAssetsAdapter(data);
        id = agentAssetsAdapter.agentAssetId; //<---
        //...
   }
//...
}
```

Here you overwrite with every bind iteration the asset id:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AgentAssetsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (agentAssetLists != null) {    
        holder.titleName....        
        holder.assetBrand....
        //here you overwrite the id on every iteration.
        agentAssetId = agentAssetLists.get(position).getIdBrand();
        href =  ....
    }
}
```

The result is you that you get the id of the latest binded asset item in your adapter.

This could be your solution:

Adjust your interface:

```
public interface AgentAssetClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, AgentAsset item);
}
```

Implement your interface:

```
public class AgentAssetsFragment extends Fragment implements AgentAssetsAdapter.AgentAssetClickListener {


    public TextView titleName, assetRate, assetBrand;
    public RecyclerView assetRecyclerView;
    List<AgentAsset> data;
    AgentAssetsAdapter agentAssetsAdapter;
    FrameLayout mLoadingFrame;
    public SharedPreferences pref;

    public AgentAssetsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //...
        initViews();
        mLoadingFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return view;
    }

    private void initViews() {
        assetRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager assetGridManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        assetRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(assetGridManager);
        getAssets();
    }

    private void getAssets() {

        //...

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<AgentAsset>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<AgentAsset>> call, Response<List<AgentAsset>> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();

                if (statusCode == 200 && response.body() != null) {

                    List<AgentAsset> agentAssets = response.body();
                    data = agentAssets;

                    agentAssetsAdapter = new AgentAssetsAdapter(data);
                    agentAssetsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(AgentAssetsFragment.this);
                    assetRecyclerView.setAdapter(agentAssetsAdapter);
                    //id = agentAssetsAdapter.agentAssetId; //gon't know for what you use this...

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), data.size() + " results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if //...

                mLoadingFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<AgentAsset>> call, Throwable t) {
                //...
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, AgentAsset item) {
        //item.getLinks().getSelf().getHref();
        //item.getAssetId();
        //Log.d("item clicked", "item clicked" + getAdapterPosition() );
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Asset["+position+"] clicked: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Adjust your bind method in Recycler adapter;

```
public class AgentAssetsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AgentAssetsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //why static?
    //private static AgentAssetClickListener agentAssetClickListener;
    //Integer agentAssetId;
    //String href;

    public List<AgentAsset> agentAssetLists;        
    private AgentAssetClickListener agentAssetClickListener;



    public AgentAssetsAdapter(List<AgentAsset> agentAssetLists) {
        this.agentAssetLists = agentAssetLists;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return agentAssetLists.size();
    }

    public interface AgentAssetClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    @Override
    public AgentAssetsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.agent_asset_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AgentAssetsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (agentAssetLists != null) {
            AgentAsset agentA = agentAssetLists.get(position);
            holder.titleName.setText(agentA.getName());
            holder.assetBrand.setText(agentA.getBrand().getName());

            //global values were overwritten by every new agentA, what is the need for this?
            //href = agentA.getLinks().getSelf().getHref();
            //agentAssetId = agentA.getIdBrand();

            //set an onlick listener to the itemView and call the agentAssetClickListener.onItemClick();
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(agentAssetClickListener != null){
                        agentAssetClickListener.onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), agentA);
                    }
                }
            });

            if (agentA.getRank() == -1) {
                holder.agentRank.setText("");
            } else {
                holder.agentRank.setText(String.valueOf(agentA.getRank()));
            }

            if (Objects.equals(agentA.getRate().getAvailable().toString(), "0")) {
                holder.assetRate.setText("nil");
            } else {
                holder.assetRate.setText(String.valueOf(agentA.getRate().getValue()));
            }

            if (Objects.equals(agentA.getBestRate().getAvailable().toString(), "0")) {
                holder.agentRate.setText("nil");
            } else {
                holder.agentRate.setText(String.valueOf(agentA.getBestRate().getValue()));
            }

        } else {

            holder.resultCount.setText("No Assets, Try Later");
        }

    }

    public void addItems(List<AgentAsset> asResponse, int index) {
        //...
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView titleName, assetRate, assetBrand, agentRate, agentRank, resultCount;
        ImageView assetImage;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            resultCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultCountId);
            titleName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentAssetTitleId);
            assetRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.assetRateId);
            assetBrand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentAssetBrandId);
            agentRank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentRankId);
            agentRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.agentAssetRateId);

            //no need anymore
            //itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            //img_android = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(AgentAssetClickListener agentAssetClickListener) {
        this.agentAssetClickListener = agentAssetClickListener;

    }
}
```

The listener of *AgentAssetClickListener* gets the item via *onItemClick(int, AgentAsset)* so you can get your item brand id via a getter method of the *AgentAsset* class. 
If the id is still the same, then there is an issue in your data structure creation.

**Edit:** Extended the answer for better understanding.

Comment: I'm not getting the position, but when I use getAdapterPosition() , it returns the corresponding position, but the id is returning the last element's id which binding to the list

Comment: How do you receive the id for the details from the List?

Comment: using this > agentAsset.getIdAsset()

Comment: before that I used getAdapterPosition()

Comment: Then your solution would be the second part of my answer, let a controller (or something else) listen to the item clicks.

Comment: Try to use my solution, use debug  to identify the item (if you click different views in the recyclerview, the listener should get the item connected to the view) then watch for the id. When the items are different but the id is the same then yes, it could be an issue in the logic for the List creation.

Comment: I updated my answer that you can get a better understanding for my solution.

Comment: Still not getting the result.

Comment: Hm, then it would be helpful to have more code for the issue. Currently, its looks like an issue with the way how you track the clicks and handling the data/values between the adapter and the listener.

Comment: Yes I think so. I am stuck with this for 2 days. I hope to get a way from this soon.